# Using a free API which licensed “For personal / non-commercial projects” in website with banners

Tags: licensing, api

if using in a website a free API that has the following license: For personal / non-commercial projects. under Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International License.

https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/

Can the website that uses the API have some banners ? (affiliates / google ads, etc.) or by having the banners the website considers then a Commercial and then need to purchase a license for the API?

Answer (score 2):

The NC clause in CC licenses is very vague and says that your usage must not be "primarily intended for or directed toward commercial advantage or monetary compensation".

If you are unsure if your usage of the API falls within that definition or not, your best bet is to ask the publisher of the API if they consider showing ads on a site using their API to be a Commercial use or not. They are anyway the ones that determine if you would get into legal trouble for violating their license or not.